# Why does the text on the Pentaho Data Integration work page look strange?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am using Pentaho Data Integration. But after I opened Spoon.bat, I did not recognize and understand why the text display on the work page became like this.

[image]

I have tried to find the settings to change the language but nothing. Does anyone know the cause and solution of this problem? This problem has appeared since the first time I installed it.

Comment: Is this only happening for your "supermarket" transformation, or for all your transformations and jobs? Does it also happen when you create a new transformation, create a single step in it, save it, and then try to load it?